# Is it possible to find the next number with only 3 numbers?

Tags: algorithm

I'm trying to write an algorithm fits these numbers but i can't :

> x = 0.5, y = 5, z = 10, a = ??

I tried different equations and i got 15 or 15.5.

> x*=10 = 5, y*=10 = 50, z*=10 = 100

so , **y = 10*x** and **z = 20*x** then **a = 30*x = 5*30 = 150**

or , **y = x+45** and **z = y+50 = 50** then **a = z+55 = 155**

so any suggestion, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to one of the corollaries of the [fundamental theorem of algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_algebra), `a` can equal *any complex number* depending on the equation that binds `x`, `y`, `z` and `a`.

That said, I`d recommend you to clarify the task.

Comment: thanks sir you answered my answer that's not possible with only three numbers ?? so i have to get the forth one

Comment: @stackuser, basically yes. You have to get `a` from the same source that gave you `x`, `y` and `z`, since there is no way to uniquely determine `a` without knowing the equation.